# Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: EACCES: permission denied, lstat '/mnt/c/DumpStack.log.tmp'

Tags: webpack

I run `npm run watch` on WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS). But get the following error.

```
Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: EACCES: permission denied, lstat '/mnt/c/DumpStack.log.tmp'
Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: EACCES: permission denied, lstat '/mnt/c/hiberfil.sys'
Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: EACCES: permission denied, lstat '/mnt/c/pagefile.sys'
Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: EACCES: permission denied, lstat '/mnt/c/swapfile.sys'
```

This is my webpack config

```
const path = require('path');
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "main": './views/js/main.js'
    },
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        filename: 'js/[name].js',
        chunkFilename: 'js/[id].[chunkhash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                enforce: "pre",
                use: ["source-map-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            importLoaders: 1,
                        }
                    },
                    { loader: 'postcss-loader' }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: devMode ? 'css/[name].css' : 'css/[name].[hash].css'
        })
    ],
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map'
}
```

Is there anyone with the same problem?
How did you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

ubuntu doesn't like the fact that you are trying to write files in /mnt/c. Since WSL doesn't always tie in correctly with ubuntu's permission systems, even with sudo you cannot change the permissions of those files.

I'd recommend changing directories to somewhere you know your user has ownership of (e.g. your documents library or usr/foldername), and trying again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the location of your files. They should be somewhere under /home/user not in /mnt/...

See here: https://github.com/webpack/watchpack/issues/187

Comment: sometime you may want to access /mnt/c to execute programs like vs code. In this case, this error may be caused by a unclean shutdown, i.e. app not properly shutdown and app still writing to file system. i fixed error by reboot the system and do a sudo apt update.